# Metadata Preservation in Clojure

Tags: clojure, metadata

From [ClojureScript Unraveled](https://funcool.github.io/clojurescript-unraveled/):

> As long as the functions that derive new data structures return
>   collections with the same type, metadata will be preserved; this is
>   not true if the types change due to the transformation.

Yet

```
(def v (with-meta [0 1 2 3] {:foo :bar}))
;; => [0 1 2 3]

(def sv (subvec v 0 2))
;; => [0 1]

(meta sv)
;; => nil ; where did the metadata?
```

Why is the metadata lost? Doesn't `subvec` return a collection with the same type as `v`, namely a vector?

Comment: Did you read the next sentence? "...this is not true if the types change due to the transformation. To ilustrate this point, let’s see what happens when we derive a seq or a subvector from a vector"

Comment: @muhuk But the type does *not* change when you use `subvec`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to preserve meta information in this case, subvec returns an entirely new vector that has nothing to do with the previous one and drops the meta information in the process.

```
(def sv (with-meta (subvec v 0 2) (meta v)))
```

Most of the functions will preserve meta information the way you are using subvec for example.

As @muhuk pointed out:

https://github.com/funcool/clojurescript-unraveled/blob/master/src/language-advanced.adoc#values